# EntityFramework Core correct initial data workflow while developing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF and I'm trying to develop a small MVC Core test application with it. I'm starting with the shipped sample application that comes with it. In it the DatabaseContext is already created because it stores authentication data in it.

Since I don't want to have 2 databases I'm using the existing one. I do the mapping, migration and update on the database. Then when I need my data back to initial seed I manually delete the entire database apply the migration/update again.

Is there any way to force EF to recreate the entire database on every run and then do the migration/update?

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is a little old, I think the solution is to use

`context.Database.EnsureCreated()/EnsureDeleted()`

further help can be found here:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3042